# Generate PropTypes from TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

I am using React with TypeScript. I am also using PropTypes.
TypeScript is intended for compile time type checking while PropTypes validate passed props on run time (development mode).
So I found myself writing types twice. Both TypeScript and PropTypes. For example, component ListingsList:

```
interface ListingsListProps {
    listings: Listing[];
    height: number;
    width: number;
    rowHeight: number;
    forwardedRef?: Ref<List>;
    className?: string;
}

const ListingsList: FunctionComponent<ListingsListProps> = props => {
...
...
};

ListingsList.propTypes = {
    listings: PropTypes.arrayOf(listingPropType.isRequired).isRequired,
    height: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    width: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    rowHeight: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    forwardedRef: PropTypes.shape({ current: PropTypes.instanceOf(List).isRequired }),
    className: PropTypes.string,
};
```

Each time I made a mistake (defining a property differently in PropTypes and in TypeScript), I get typescript error. Sometimes I don't really know how to define the PropType. For example, when passing History property from 'history'. I don't want to define History PropType myself because it has a complicated shape.
I saw there are projects that generates TypeScript from PropTypes but I really don't like it because TypeScript is much stronger, I can define more detailed types.
I am looking for a way to generate PropTypes from TypeScript, and I think this is a must feature for React developers.

Comment: Why not just omit the proptypes? Typescript makes it obsolete..

Comment: You dont need proptypes, Typescript will prompt you (via Editor and compiler command line) if you are missing any props which are required

Comment: @MuratKaragöz Eventually you run the code and in real world things are unexpected and even though I have TypeScript, one component can get prop with incorrect type. Remember, apps usually works with apis and there isn't a system (no that I know) that enforces a contract with types. So all my api responses starts with "any" type and I force the response to be something.
Another possibility is where part of the app isn't with types yet.

Comment: I think your API calls should be mapped to models. If mapping fails then you have your runtime check. And about contract system while using apis https://grpc.io/ :)

Comment: @MichałK. You know it's not practical approach for each react application, and yet, there is no perfect world and we use use TypeScript casting, and do sometimes some hacks to fast solve issues. I am looking for a simple way to protect my app. Since I already wrote types using TypeScript, I want also the PropTypes. There is no need to escape from this feature request.

Comment: Sine you wrote types for ts you do not need proptypes. It is like code duplication IMO. You could use constructor validation if you really need runtime check for API models.

Comment: @MichałK. I don't want to invent a new system as an alternative of what already invented. I want to use the built in proptypes but I don't want to repeat the types.

Comment: @MichałK: what if you consume a 3rd party API that doesn't give you access to models or type information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [babel-plugin-typescript-to-proptypes](https://github.com/milesj/babel-plugin-typescript-to-proptypes). It requires either the `@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx` plugin or the `@babel/preset-react` preset.

Use `npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-typescript-to-proptypes` to install.

And here is a sample `babel.config.js`:

```
const plugins = [];

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  plugins.push('babel-plugin-typescript-to-proptypes');
}

module.exports = {
  // Required
  presets: ['@babel/preset-typescript', '@babel/preset-react']
  plugins,
};
```

Comment: and what to do with this? For me there is no change at all if I add this to my project after npm start command.? There is any magic command to generate propTypes? It is not exaplained in the documentation.  I have: 
```
import React from 'react';

interface Props {
  counter: number;
}

const Heading: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
  return <h1>This is counter {props.counter}</h1>;
};

export default Heading;
```